# Getting undefined error at JavaScript array quiz

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, undefined, typeerror

I am trying to make a simple multiple choice-like quiz using data from an array, but I am getting an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.

The possible choices should be 4, with the correct answer being the first choice. I have tried searching online for solutions, but I do not know what is causing the error and how to fix it:

```js
var masterlist = [
  ["Indonesia", "Jakarta"],
  ["Malaysia", "Kuala Lumpur"],
  ["Philippines", "Manila"],
  ["Singapore", "Singapore"],
  ["Thailand", "Bangkok"],
  ["Vietnam", "Hanoi"]
];

function randomNoRepeats(array) {
  var copy = array.slice(0);
  return function() {
    if (copy.length < 1) {
      copy = array.slice(0);
    }
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length);
    var item = copy[index];
    copy.splice(index, 1);
    return item;
  };
}
var chooser = randomNoRepeats(masterlist); //randomize choices
//console.log(chooser());

var quizArea = document.getElementById("test-area");

var a = []; // new empty array to store randomized items
var c = []; // new empty array to store randomized items (copy)
var b;
var correctAnswer;

for (var i = 0; i < masterlist.length; i++) {
  b = chooser();
  a.push(b);
}
c = a;
//console.log("a", a, a.length); // ERROR here; expected an array length of 6

for (var i = 0; i < masterlist.length; i++) {
  correctAnswer = c[i];

  var index = a.indexOf(correctAnswer); // remove correct answer from list of other/wrong choices
  a.splice(index, 1);

  var otherChoices = a.slice(0, 3); // choose only 3 wrong/other choices

  var question = document.createElement("p");
  question.innerHTML = "What is the capital of " + correctAnswer[0] + "?"; // ERROR

  var answers = document.createElement("p");
  answers.innerHTML = correctAnswer[1] + ", " + otherChoices[0][1] + ", " + otherChoices[1][1] + ", " + otherChoices[2][1]; // place correct answer at index 0; TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

  quizArea.appendChild(question);
  quizArea.appendChild(answers);

}
```

```html
<div id="test-area"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from the statement `c = a;`. It does not copy the array. Both `c` and `a` reference the same array object.

This means that the line `a.splice(index, 1)` changes `a` AND `c` in place.

---

One solution here is to use a real copy of `a` in your last *for loop*.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < masterlist.length; i++) {
  c = a.slice(0); // or c = [...a];
  
  // use `c` here
}
```

```js
var masterlist = [
  ["Indonesia", "Jakarta"],
  ["Malaysia", "Kuala Lumpur"],
  ["Philippines", "Manila"],
  ["Singapore", "Singapore"],
  ["Thailand", "Bangkok"],
  ["Vietnam", "Hanoi"]
];

function randomNoRepeats(array) {
  var copy = array.slice(0);
  return function() {
    if (copy.length < 1) {
      copy = array.slice(0);
    }
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length);
    var item = copy[index];
    copy.splice(index, 1);
    return item;
  };
}
var chooser = randomNoRepeats(masterlist); //randomize choices
//console.log(chooser());

var quizArea = document.getElementById("test-area");

var a = []; // new empty array to store randomized items
var c;
var b;
var correctAnswer;

for (var i = 0; i < masterlist.length; i++) {
  b = chooser();
  a.push(b);
}
//console.log("a", a, a.length); // ERROR here; expected an array length of 6

for (var i = 0; i < masterlist.length; i++) {
  c = a.slice(0);

  correctAnswer = c[i];

  var index = c.indexOf(correctAnswer); // remove correct answer from list of other/wrong choices
  c.splice(index, 1);

  var otherChoices = c.slice(0, 3); // choose only 3 wrong/other choices
  
  var question = document.createElement("p");
  question.innerHTML = "What is the capital of " + correctAnswer[0] + "?"; // ERROR

  var answers = document.createElement("p");
  answers.innerHTML = correctAnswer[1] + ", " + otherChoices[0][1] + ", " + otherChoices[1][1] + ", " + otherChoices[2][1]; // place correct answer at index 0; TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

  quizArea.appendChild(question);
  quizArea.appendChild(answers);

}
```

```html
<div id="test-area"></div>
```